# Rails development server slow after exceptions raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

I have a local development server running Rails 6, using foreman to run it alongside a webpacker server.

I recently noticed that any time I get an exception - from the most simple thing like a nilClass error on a page - after I fix the issue and reload, my laptop starts overworking it's fan and I get the repeating errors below:-

```
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | activesupport (6.0.3.5) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:126:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | rack (2.2.3) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | actionpack (6.0.3.5) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:82:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | honeybadger (4.7.3) lib/honeybadger/rack/error_notifier.rb:33:in `block in call'
01:55:19 web.1     | honeybadger (4.7.3) lib/honeybadger/agent.rb:403:in `with_rack_env'
01:55:19 web.1     | honeybadger (4.7.3) lib/honeybadger/rack/error_notifier.rb:30:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | honeybadger (4.7.3) lib/honeybadger/rack/user_feedback.rb:31:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | honeybadger (4.7.3) lib/honeybadger/rack/user_informer.rb:21:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | webpacker (4.3.0) lib/webpacker/dev_server_proxy.rb:23:in `perform_request'
01:55:19 web.1     | rack-proxy (0.6.5) lib/rack/proxy.rb:57:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | railties (6.0.3.5) lib/rails/engine.rb:527:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | newrelic_rpm (6.2.0.354) lib/new_relic/agent/instrumentation/middleware_tracing.rb:99:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/configuration.rb:227:in `call'
01:55:19 web.1     | puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:706:in `handle_request'
01:55:19 web.1     | puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:476:in `process_client'
01:55:19 web.1     | puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/server.rb:334:in `block in run'
01:55:19 web.1     | puma (3.12.6) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:135:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

I've no idea where to begin looking to resolve this issue.  Wondering if it's being caused by airbrake or new relic, or if these gems are just reacting to the error.

Comment: I have a similar gem setup and not experiencing that. If you think a gem is causing this then try removing it/them one by one from gemfile and test again. What server are you using on your local?

Comment: We can't see the error, just a stacktrace

Comment: Do you need NewRelic in development ? Probably it would be good to keep NewRelic gem in the production name space inside your Gemfile.

Comment: I really doubt its a server issue. You can always try a different server that supports the same concurrency model (i.e., iodine) to see if the issue is related to the server. If the issue persists, than you know it's not Puma.